# How to display a string javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML file I have a div with id="list".
Now I want to display a string from my javascript in my html. page. but nothning
happen. In my html file, i've imported the srcipt file. Here's how it looks in my script file:

```
var namesArray = ["lars", "bo", "ib", "peter", "jan", "frederik"];

var list = namesArray.map(name=>"<li>"+name+"</li>");
var listAsStr ="<ul>" + list.join("") + "<ul>";
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = listAsStr;
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementById("list")`? Missing  `/` at closing `<ul>`

Comment: Is your script in the head of the document? If so, move it to be the last HTML element on the page before the body ends i.e. `<script>...</script></body></html>`

Comment: did you wrap your code inside [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)?

Comment: my html file and javascript file are in two different file. gaetanM. No i haven't why should I need to do that, usually I don't need to do that.

Comment: Can you include the HTML at the question and create a stacksnippet to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Questions seeking help with ("**why isn't/how to make this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you wrap your script in window.onload you can put it anywhere in your page (or external file). it will check if the window has loading before targeting the DOM elements. I wrote an answer for you and i've tested the code. It works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the JavaScript code after your dom and also wrapped with Script tag.

Example: This will work since we rendered the HTML first and then executed the js into it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>This Will WorK</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div id="list" ></div>

 <script>
  var namesArray = ["lars", "bo", "ib", "peter", "jan", "frederik"];

  var list = namesArray.map(name=>"<li>"+name+"</li>");
  var listAsStr ="<ul>" + list.join("") + "<ul>";

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = listAsStr;
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this will **NOT** work since the JavaScript is being executed before dom rendered. Also this will probably throw an error `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"` because getElementById will not be able to find the associated dom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>This Will Not WorK</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <script>
  var namesArray = ["lars", "bo", "ib", "peter", "jan", "frederik"];

  var list = namesArray.map(name=>"<li>"+name+"</li>");
  var listAsStr ="<ul>" + list.join("") + "<ul>";

  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = listAsStr;
 </script>
  
 <div id="list" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lfty what if i moved the javascript to a specific file call list.js. and then in my html file directed to my script at the end of the body like this <script src="list"></script>. why didn't it work???

Comment: If you wrap your script in window.onload you can put it anywhere. it will check if the window has loading before targeting the DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks everyone. it seems everything works fine now, even when the html and script are separated in 2 files!!!

Comment: @JohnnyVan it should also work if you link correctly. Maybe you forgot to add type="text/javascript"  in your script tag ?

Btw if that doesn't work, try the onload method showed by Sarah

Comment: @JohnnyVan That's great :)

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you're targeting DOM elements (i.e you want to use `document.getElementById("my-element")` or similar) you need to first check if the document has loaded.

You can do this in either of the following ways:

```
window.onload = function(){
  //Now that the window has loaded we can target DOM elements here
}
```

OR

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  //Now that the contents of the DOM have loaded we can target DOM elements here
});
```

So a full example (putting your script code in an external file i.e `list.js`) would look like this:

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8">
<title>My list website</title>
<script src="list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="list"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## list.js

```
window.onload = function(){
    //We use window.onload to check the window has loaded so we can target DOM elements
    var namesArray = ["lars", "bo", "ib", "peter", "jan", "frederik"];
    var list = namesArray.map(name=>"<li>"+name+"</li>");
    var listAsStr ="<ul>" + list.join("") + "<ul>";
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = listAsStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

place your code in this and it will work

window.onload = function() {}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a succinct way to do it with template strings. Just wrap everything in a function you assign to `window.onload`:

```html
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    const namesArray = ['lars', 'bo', 'ib', 'peter', 'jan', 'frederik'];
    const list = `<ul>${namesArray.map(name => `<li>${name}</li>`).join('')}</ul>`;
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = list;
  };
</script>

<div id="list"></div>
```